# How to avoid passing param to template instantiation of reference-based helper class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, reference

I've got a 3rd-party module that provides a number of Object instances. I'd like do some additional actions with the objects, however I have no chance to create a derived class. Instead I created a wrapper that gets a reference and implements additional helper functions. (see Helper class below.)

Is there any way to avoid passing T param to the template instantiation, i.e. use `Helper(r)` rather than `Helper<const Object>(r)`?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct Object
{
    bool constOp() const { return false; }
    bool nonConstOp() { return true; }
};

template <class T>
struct Helper
{
    Helper(T &r) : m_ref(r) {}
    bool anotherConstOp() const { return m_ref.get().constOp(); }
    bool anotherNonConstOp() { return m_ref.get().nonConstOp(); }
private:
    reference_wrapper<T> m_ref;
};

int main() 
{
    {
        Object r;
        Helper<Object> h(r);
        cout << h.anotherConstOp() << endl;
        cout << h.anotherNonConstOp() << endl;
    }
    {
        const Object r;
        cout << Helper<const Object>(r).anotherConstOp() << endl;
        // doesn't compile nonconst - ok
        //cout << Helper<const Object>(r).anotherNonConstOp() << endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `std` namespace you find helper functions such as [`std::make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) and [`std::make_optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/make_optional) for this purpose. You can use

```
template<class T>
Helper<T> make_helper(T& object) {
  return Helper<T>(object);
}
```

and then

```
auto h = make_helper(r);
```

I suppose you have a good reason why you wish to use that `Helper` wrapper. In your example there is no need. You can use a free function instead:

```
bool anotherConstOp(const Object& object) {
  return object.constOp();
}
```

plus overloads and/or the generic version:

```
template<class T>
bool anotherConstOp(const T& object) {
  return object.constOp();
}
```